# How to upgrade elasticbeanstalk docker version

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

Docker has a rather fast release schedule, often with important, valuable features. Amazon's elasticbeanstalk image does not get updated that often, but since you have full control over the machine, you should be able to manually update docker. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

To modify your elasticbeanstalk you can use the ebextensions mechanism to download a newer docker version and override the existing version with it. Just create a .ebextensions/docker.conf file in your elasticbeanstalk directory with the contents that follows.

Configs may break, as is the case currently for docker-1.11, that needs the "daemon" parameter when starting. You can play with the configs to fix that, as shown here. As a bonus, I also changed the docker storage path, so larger images do not take over all your root filesystem space.

```
files:
  "/root/docker-1.11.2.tgz":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    source: https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-1.11.2.tgz

commands:
  01installdocker:
    command: tar xvzf /root/docker-1.11.2.tgz -C /usr/bin/ --strip 1 && rm /root/docker-1.11.2.tgz
  02configuredocker:
    command: sed -i.tmp -e 's%OPTIONS=%OPTIONS="-g /media/ephemeral0/docker"%' /etc/sysconfig/docker && sed -i.tmp -e 's%nohup $exec -d%nohup $exec daemon%' /etc/init.d/docker
  03restartdocker:
    command: /etc/init.d/docker restart
```